# No se guardan los datos al usar un método de una clase

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Buen día, estoy haciendo un programa en donde se deben pedir 6 datos de un alumno y guardarlos, después el usuario puede ver los datos de los alumnos guardados y se deberían mostrar los datos, pero parece que no se guardan. Si pongo estos 2 mismos códigos por separado me funciona correctamente el programa, pero como los tengo separados en 2 métodos distintos, parece que no guarda los datos registrados. Dejo un ejemplo de lo que me pasa como lo tengo y lo que pasa cuando junto los códigos (no me sirven juntos porque no es el propósito del ejercicio).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
void Alumno::registrar() { //Método para guardar los datos de los alumnos
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "***********Bienvenido al registro de alumnos***********" << endl;

        cout << "\nIngrese el nombre del alumno No. " << n + 1 << ": " << endl;
        getline(cin, nombre);

        cout << "\nIngrese los apellidos del alumno No. " << n + 1 << ": " << endl;
        getline(cin, apellido);

        cout << "\nIngrese la edad del alumno No. " << n + 1 << ": " << endl;
        getline(cin, edad);

        cout << "\nIngrese el no. de control escolar del alumno No. " << n + 1 << ": " << endl;
        getline(cin, noControl);

        cout << "\nIngrese el sexo del alumno No. " << n + 1 << ": " << endl;
        getline(cin, sexo);

        cout << "\nIngrese el semestre del alumno No. " << n + 1 << ": " << endl;
        getline(cin, semestre);

        datos[i][0] = nombre;
        datos[i][1] = apellido;
        datos[i][2] = edad;
        datos[i][3] = noControl;
        datos[i][4] = sexo;
        datos[i][5] = semestre;

        cout << "\nLos datos del alumno " << nombre << " " << apellido << " han sido registrados con el no. de control: " << noControl << endl;

    }
}

    void Alumno::consulta() { //Aquí es como muestro los datos
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            cout << "Nombre: " << datos[i][0] << "\n";
            cout << "Apellido: " << datos[i][1] << "\n";
            cout << "Edad: " << datos[i][2] << "\n";
            cout << "No Control: " << datos[i][3] << "\n";
            cout << "Sexo: " << datos[i][4] << "\n";
            cout << "Semestre: " << datos[i][5] << "\n\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes cargar el código completo o al menos la declaración de la clase (por las variables)?

Answer (score 0):

por lo que explicas, sucede que tus variables son Locales al método. O sea, solo se mantienen los datos mientras estés "Dentro" del método. Cuando sales del método (terminan las instrucciones), los datos se pierden, se destruyen. Para poder usar un metodo que Registre los datos y otro que los Lea, las variables han de ser Globales (creadas fuera de cualquier método).